# Referencing .NET DLLs and deployment

Tags: .net, dll

I have a v3.5 project which builds an exe and it references few other custom (other team) .NET DLLs

These referred DLLs in turn refer to some 3rd party DLLs.

My question is when i deploy it on server. I just deploy my own exe and the DLLs i directly refer.

What about all those 2nd level underlying 3rd party DLLs. They do not exist on deployment server, still my binary seems to run. **How ?**

Does not complain of DLL not found. In Output, it does not even show loading of those 3rd party DLLs. May be those 3rd party dll code is not actually used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does not complain of DLL not found. In Output, it does not even show loading of those 3rd party DLLs. May be those 3rd party dll code is not actually used ?

This sounds like the most likely explanation.  They won't be loaded until they're actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

use this application to find out what is going on 
http://www.dependencywalker.com/
just open all dlls with it and test if they are really dependent.